# Shortening the jQuery when writing css into a parent and child

Tags: jquery

Is it possible to shorten the below to save writing `css()` twice for `this` and the `span` which is a child of `this`

```
$('.link .partner li a').each(function(index, element) {
    var linklogo = $(this).prop('class');
    $(this).css({
        "background-image":"url(/assets/img/link/"+linklogo+".png)"     
    });
    $(this).find('span').css({
        "background-image":"url(/assets/img/link/"+linklogo+".png)"     
    });
});
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use [addBack()](http://api.jquery.com/addBack/) (previously named `andSelf()`):

```
$(this).find("span").addBack().css({
    "background-image": "url(/assets/img/link/" + linklogo + ".png)"
});
```

This will add the initial contents of the set (`$(this)`) to the elements returned by `find()`.

Comment: Works a treat! Thank you for your help!